Is there a way to use an enum made within a class as param for a data class within the same class?
I have a class which consists of an enum and data class. How to I pass the enum as param type for the data class?
I tried the following:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum

class ABC:
    class Enum1(Enum):
        VAL1 = 1
        VAL2 = 2

    @dataclass
    class Settings:
        setting1: int
        setting2: int
        setting3: Enum1

For the above code python has been giving an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    class ABC:
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 10, in ABC
    class Settings:
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 13, in Settings
    setting3: Enum1
              ^^^^^
NameError: name 'Enum1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Enum'?


just don't nest class definitions, it doesn't do anything except make make them harder to work with.
